# Combination of reflection symmetries in $\mathbb{E^4}$

Tags: euclidean-geometry, rotations, isometry, reflection, 4-manifolds

Is the combination between point reflection (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Point_reflection) symmetry and hyperplane(or axial using Hodge duality) reflection symmetry (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reflection_symmetry) in $\mathbb{E^4}$ possible for a given orientation of $\mathbb{E^4}$?

I think point reflections for point $P$ in $2n$ dimensions give 180º rotations in $n$ orthogonal planes intersecting in $P$ that preserve space orientation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I *think* you're asking whether hyperplane / axial reflections in $\mathbb{E}^4$ preserve orientation. If that's the question, then the answer is no, by a very standard argument: after conjugating by a rotation if needed, those reflections can be written in matrix form as $\mathrm{diag}(1, -1, -1, -1)$ or $\mathrm{diag}(-1, 1, 1, 1)$. Since the determinants of these matrices are $-1$, they both invert orientation. (By contrast, note that the point reflection matrix is $\mathrm{diag}(-1, -1, -1, -1)$ and thus preserves orientation, just as you suspected, since the determinant is $1$.)

Comment: @bonif I'm still a little bit confused. If you're asking whether there are shapes that are symmetric under both of those symmetries, then the answer is yes — for instance, a sphere centered at the point of reflection, with the hyperplane of reflection going through that point. More generally, 'inversions' around some point and reflections about one or more hyperplanes (presumably not through that point) will generate a group of transformations, just like they do in the planar case, and there will be structures invariant under that group.